# How to get the stream URL from android app?

Tags: android, flutter, camera

I want to get the stream url from an android app to open the stream video elsewhere
using EZVIZ TY1 1080p 360-Degree camera or Mi Home Security Camera 360°1080P

I expect to get the url of the stream video and open it on a web page.

Answer (score 2):

If your running the android app on your phone, or any device for that matter you would need to install a pass-through "man in the middle" proxy (such as Charles or Fiddler) and set your device to connect through your machine - you'll be able to inspect all network traffic from there that the app is making when you load services/sites or any network traffic for that matter. You can filter out down to exactly what you need and copy the request URL so you can reuse it.

Note that this works with nearly all but encrypted traffic, so never any promises but that would be the ideal approach to getting what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [EZUIKIT](https://github.com/Ezviz-OpenBiz/EZUIKit-JavaScript-npm) to help you get the URL of the stream video and open it on a web page.